# Android FCM onTokenRefresh() is only called in emulator

Tags: android

I got the problem when I used the Firebase onTokenRefresh() function.
I saw the below block quotes.

> onTokenRefresh in FirebaseInstanceIdService is only called when a new token is generated. If your app was previously installed and generated a token then onTokenRefresh would not be called. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the app to force the generation of a new token, this would cause onTokenRefresh to be called.

But it was only applied to my first emulator not the device.

When I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app to force the generation of a new token in the emulator, the token was generated.
But in the device, the token wasn't generated.
And I also tried to install the app by creating another emulator to see if a token was generated. But, it also didn't.

What is the problem?.. 
Here is my code.

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {

    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
```

and Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".FireBaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".FirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
</application>
```

Please someone helps me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that your device is connected to the internet.
It may take a few seconds to generate the token so check the token not directly after the start of the application.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Your first answer is correct.
When I commented about 15 minutes ago, I didn't understand what you mentioned correctly.
As you mentioned, the token isn't created right after the app starts..
Really thank you for replying!!!